Unable to start airflow celery worker with redis
I am running an airflow cluster where each component is on different servers, and can connect to each other. I can run web, scheduler, and triggerer. but failed to start a celery worker, when I run the following command airflow celery worker
I get the following error log;
 -------------- celery@insairflwstb03 v5.4.0 (opalescent)
--- ***** ----- 
-- ******* ---- Linux-4.18.0-477.13.1.el8_8.x86_64-x86_64-with-glibc2.28 2024-05-14 23:11:49
- *** --- * --- 
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         airflow.providers.celery.executors.celery_executor:0x7fb98a25d090
- ** ---------- .> transport:   redis://:**@10.220.14.97:6379/0
- ** ---------- .> results:     postgresql+psycopg2://airflow_user:**@tbauba:5432/airflow
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: {min=12, max=16} (prefork)
-- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
--- ***** ----- 
 -------------- [queues]
                .> default          exchange=default(direct) key=default
                

[tasks]
  . airflow.providers.celery.executors.celery_executor_utils.execute_command

[2024-05-14 23:11:51,830: WARNING/MainProcess] /home/airflow/envs/airflow/lib/python3.11/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py:508: CPendingDeprecationWarning: The broker_connection_retry configuration setting will no longer determine
whether broker connection retries are made during startup in Celery 6.0 and above.
If you wish to retain the existing behavior for retrying connections on startup,
you should set broker_connection_retry_on_startup to True.
  warnings.warn(

[2024-05-14 23:11:51,839: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to redis://:**@10.220.14.97:6379/0
[2024-05-14 23:11:51,840: WARNING/MainProcess] /home/airflow/envs/airflow/lib/python3.11/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py:508: CPendingDeprecationWarning: The broker_connection_retry configuration setting will no longer determine
whether broker connection retries are made during startup in Celery 6.0 and above.
If you wish to retain the existing behavior for retrying connections on startup,
you should set broker_connection_retry_on_startup to True.
  warnings.warn(

[2024-05-14 23:11:51,843: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2024-05-14 23:11:52,855: CRITICAL/MainProcess] Unrecoverable error: ResponseError("Command # 1 (DEL 3b04eb4d-2b58-3b16-815f-0e0ba021108e.reply.celery.pidbox) of pipeline caused error: unknown command 'DEL', with args beginning with: '3b04eb4d-2b58-3b16-815f-0e0ba021108e.reply.celery.pidbox' ")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/envs/airflow/lib/python3.11/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 1364, in _execute_transaction
    response = self.parse_response(connection, "_")
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/airflow/envs/airflow/lib/python3.11/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 1432, in parse_response
    result = Redis.parse_response(self, connection, command_name, **options)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/airflow/envs/airflow/lib/python3.11/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 562, in parse_response
    response = connection.read_response()
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/airflow/envs/airflow/lib/python3.11/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 536, in read_response
    raise response
redis.exceptions.ExecAbortError: Transaction discarded because of previous errors.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/envs/airflow/lib/python3.11/site-packages/celery/worker/worker.py", line 202, in start
    self.blueprint.start(self)
  File "/home/airflow/envs/airflow/lib/python3.11/site-packages/celery/bootsteps.py", line 116, in start
    step.start(parent)
  File "/home/airflow/envs/airflow/lib/python3.11/site-packages/celery/bootsteps.py", line 365, in start
    return self.obj.start()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/airflow/envs/airflow/lib/python3.11/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py", line 340, in start
    blueprint.start(self)
  File "/home/airflow/envs/airflow/lib/python3.11/site-packages/celery/bootsteps.py", line 116, in start
    step.start(parent)
  File "/home/airflow/envs/airflow/lib/python3.11/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/mingle.py", line 37, in start
    self.sync(c)
  File "/home/airflow/envs/airflow/lib/python3.11/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/mingle.py", line 41, in sync
    replies = self.send_hello(c)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/airflow/envs/airflow/lib/python3.11/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/mingle.py", line 54, in send_hello
    replies = inspect.hello(c.hostname, our_revoked._data) or {}
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/airflow/envs/airflow/lib/python3.11/site-packages/celery/app/control.py", line 389, in hello
    return self._request('hello', from_node=from_node, revoked=revoked)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/airflow/envs/airflow/lib/python3.11/site-packages/celery/app/control.py", line 106, in _request
    return self._prepare(self.app.control.broadcast(
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/airflow/envs/airflow/lib/python3.11/site-packages/celery/app/control.py", line 776, in broadcast
    return self.mailbox(conn)._broadcast(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/airflow/envs/airflow/lib/python3.11/site-packages/kombu/pidbox.py", line 346, in _broadcast
    return self._collect(reply_ticket, limit=limit,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/airflow/envs/airflow/lib/python3.11/site-packages/kombu/pidbox.py", line 393, in _collect
    chan.after_reply_message_received(queue.name)
  File "/home/airflow/envs/airflow/lib/python3.11/site-packages/kombu/transport/virtual/base.py", line 552, in after_reply_message_received
    self.queue_delete(queue)
  File "/home/airflow/envs/airflow/lib/python3.11/site-packages/kombu/transport/virtual/base.py", line 548, in queue_delete
    self._delete(queue, exchange, *meta, **kwargs)
  File "/home/airflow/envs/airflow/lib/python3.11/site-packages/kombu/transport/redis.py", line 1055, in _delete
    pipe.execute()
  File "/home/airflow/envs/airflow/lib/python3.11/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 1500, in execute
    return conn.retry.call_with_retry(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/airflow/envs/airflow/lib/python3.11/site-packages/redis/retry.py", line 46, in call_with_retry
    return do()
           ^^^^
  File "/home/airflow/envs/airflow/lib/python3.11/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 1501, in <lambda>
    lambda: execute(conn, stack, raise_on_error),
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/airflow/envs/airflow/lib/python3.11/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 1367, in _execute_transaction
    raise errors[0][1]
  File "/home/airflow/envs/airflow/lib/python3.11/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 1357, in _execute_transaction
    self.parse_response(connection, "_")
  File "/home/airflow/envs/airflow/lib/python3.11/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 1432, in parse_response
    result = Redis.parse_response(self, connection, command_name, **options)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/airflow/envs/airflow/lib/python3.11/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 562, in parse_response
    response = connection.read_response()
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/airflow/envs/airflow/lib/python3.11/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 536, in read_response
    raise response
redis.exceptions.ResponseError: Command # 1 (DEL 3b04eb4d-2b58-3b16-815f-0e0ba021108e.reply.celery.pidbox) of pipeline caused error: unknown command 'DEL', with args beginning with: '3b04eb4d-2b58-3b16-815f-0e0ba021108e.reply.celery.pidbox' 
[2024-05-14 23:11:53 +0300] [2169994] [INFO] Handling signal: term
[2024-05-14 23:11:53 +0300] [2169996] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 2169996)
[2024-05-14 23:11:53 +0300] [2169997] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 2169997)
[2024-05-14 23:11:54 +0300] [2169994] [INFO] Shutting down: Master

